# Where can I find Zebra's CpclCrcHeader class

Tags: zebra-printers

Where can I find Zebra's CpclCrcHeader class? I say that you have managed to send a file to a Zebra printer. But I can't manage to do this. Can you help me with this issue please?

Comment: What is the real issue you are having? Can you provide some code and a stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

`CpclCrcHeader` is an internal class in the Zebra SDK. You shouldn't use it directly as it can change or go away without any warning.